# Dynamic condition in SQL statement using asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am developing an website in asp.net and I am using 2 drop-down lists.
When an item is selected in the 1st drop down list a query is executed and the output is loaded in the 2nd drop down list.

The problem is that the condition of the query is dynamic, depends on the selected item.
Query : select Series from Football where Levels='selected item value'

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Please also supply code

Comment: Please share a snippet of code as an example. Otherwise, it is hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ok, we want to select a City, (first drop down).

And then say from that, we want to select hotels.

So, two simple drop downs like this:

```
        <div style="float:left">
            Select City<br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server"
                DataTextField ="City"
                DataValueField="City"
                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:35px">
            Select Hotel<br /> 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotel" runat="server"
                DataTextField="HotelName"
                DataValueField="ID">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

And our code could be say this:
(note the auto post-back for the first drop down).

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Load first combo box
            SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT City from City Order by City");

            cboCity.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
            cboCity.DataBind();
            cboCity.Items.Insert(0, "");    // add blank (no select)
        }

    }

    protected void cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQL =
           new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, HotelName from tblhotels where City = @City");

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.SelectedItem.Text;

        cboHotel.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        cboHotel.DataBind();
    }
    DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL.Connection = conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

And thus results are this:

[image]